# ColorMatrixColorFilter equivlanet in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

My program has a method that is supposed to take an image and a color, and turn all of the pixels in that image into that color, while keeping each pixel's transparency.

This could be easily done in Android using `ColorMatrixColorFilter` without having to use nested loops to go through the entire image and change each pixel individually, which is significantly slower.

However, I recently decided to switch to libgdx, which means that I can't use the `ColorMatrixColorFilter`. Does libgdx have any classes that will do something similar, without having me to manually change each pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use textures with only white pixels (which varying alphas), and tinting them before drawing them with `SpriteBatch.setColor(r,g,b,a)`--just set back to `Color.WHITE` after.

Aside from having to pause to transform the texture pixel-by-pixel, the biggest advantage of this is that the texture doesn't need to be set in its own file, but can be put in the same TextureAtlas as all of the other textures that aren't being tinted. Because it's not necessary to bind different colored versions of the texture, `SpriteBatch` ends up making a lot fewer rendering calls, which means faster rendering.

Answer (score 1):

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setColor(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color 
take look at setColor();

Actually I do manipulate each pixel by myself and it's not that bad. You should give it a try.

Comment: Yes, that's how I currently do it, but it causes a noticeable pause, since I don't load a particular colored texture until it's actually needed (in other words, colored versions of textures are loaded on the fly).

Comment: Also, slight tangent, but the `Pixmap.getColor()` method seems to behave oddly. The documentation says that it returns an RGBA8888 value, but if I create a `Pixmap` from a `FileHandle`, the values that `getColor()` are definitely not RGBA8888, but are all over the place (-256?). If I create a new `Pixmap` using RGBA8888, then draw the first Pixmap into the second, then `getColor()` returns only values between 0-255, and happens to match up with the alpha. I use this to draw into a third `Pixmap` using `setColor()`